# AutoScroll iframe parent while dragging (Prototype & Scriptaculous)

Tags: iframe, drag-and-drop, scroll, scriptaculous

I am having an iframe on a page. The iframe resizes itself based on the content loaded in it. So, it won't be having any scroll bars.

The iframe contains a list of draggable elements (Prototype & Scriptaculous). I have to drag the elements from bottom to top or vice versa, and while dragging, the parent window should scroll accordingly. I have modified the dragdrop.js file accordingly to scroll based on "window.parent.window" element. The outcome is that the parent window scrolls from bottom to top automatically on the drag of an element, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks everyone. I think I have resolved this issue myself.

All I had to do was to calculate the position of the IFrame window and minus it from the top scroll value calculated by the drag & drop js code.